# Json object multiple array Parse, retrofit

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, gson, retrofit

I have a Json string. i couldn't onResponse with Retrofit with two List(Categories and product). How i call, callback? i should use what? not normaly a list, right?

```html
{
"Categories": [{"name":"x products",
                "products":[{}{}{}]}
                {"name":"y products",
                "products":[{}{}{}]}
                {"name":"z products",
                "products":[{}{}{}]} ],
"CoverPageURL":"xx.png",
"Location": "Canada",
"adress":"opposite of hospital"
"ProductItems": [ 
          {"large":"xx"
            "mall":"tt"}
           {"large":"yy"
            "mall":"gg"}]
"Status": {
"ErrorCode": 0,
"Error": null,
"HasError": false
  }
```

in normally i do that

```html
Call<Merchant> call = ToolApi.getApi().GetMerchant(BaseService.TOKEN);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Merchant>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Merchant> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.body() == null) {
}else{

//I bought the bottoms from another class just For example
//normaly one list and its' items. but in that case i have two list on JSON
//start
   HomePageContent homePageContent = response.body();
                    Integer errorCode = homePageContent.getStatus().getErrorCode();

                    if (errorCode == 0) {
/// What i should write here 
                        List<ItemHomePagecontent> items = homePageContent.getItems();
                        HeadRecyclerListHomePageContent.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        homePageAdapter = new HomePageAdapter(homePageContent, items, context());
                        HeadRecyclerListHomePageContent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                        HeadRecyclerListHomePageContent.setAdapter(homePageAdapter);
                        
                       //finish
}
 @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
....
```

Comment: You want to know how to parse the JSON into a POJO?

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari  I edit quesiton. No, not POJO. I want know how i put a list ? Thank you

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Check if your JSON is valid on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). Post a valid JSON then we can help properly.

Answer (score 0):

In the block `// What i should write here` should be this:
`Merchant merchant = response.body();`

In `Merchant` class should be fields which `GetMerchant` returns.

Btw your json is invalid.

Comment: No, I edit question. I want know, how put into json one list? becasuse i have 2 list on json(Categories and ProductItems)

Comment: You should create class with your two lists and other fields from json structure, after that create instance of this class and fill fields. When you can send this object via retrofit like you do with GetMerchant request @Jenni